# Matplotlib: How does one plot a 1D array of x values with y-axis corresponding to a heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I want to make a subplot for a heatmap where the y-axis matches that of the heatmap (features), but the x axis is some transformation of the mean of the binned values represented for each feature in the heatmap.  Below is an example figure:

[image: example figure -- I'm trying to make the subplot on the right]

I can make the heatmap already using imshow, and I have an array of transformed means for each feature with indices that match the heatmap array.  How can I produce the subplot on the right of my example figure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main things are setting up the axes to share the y-metric (`sharey=True`) and (as you have) setting up your the transformed data to use the same indices:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import random
from numpy import var

H = random(size=(120,80))
Hvar = var(H, axis=1)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,3), ncols=2, sharey=True, sharex=False)
plt.sca(axs[0])
plt.imshow(H) #heatmap into current axis
axs[0].set_ylim(0,120)
axs[1].scatter(Hvar, range(len(Hvar)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick and clear response.  I tried something like this but didn't quite get there.  One of those Mondays.